# Как заполнить область пересечения между кругом и функцией в JSXGraph

Tags: javascript, svg

У меня есть круг и простая функция `Math.cos(x)`

Я хочу, чтобы круг был заполнен, когда он пересекается с этой функцией (заполнить только верхнюю сторону).
Но это у меня не работает.

**Script:**

```
// circle
    var point1 = app.board.create('point', [0,0], {size: 2, strokeWidth:2 })
    var point2 = app.board.create('point', [6,0], {size: 2, strokeWidth:2 })
    var circle = app.board.create('circle', [point1,point2], {strokeColor: "#f00", strokeWidth: 2 })
    
    // function
    var func = app.board.create('functiongraph',[function(x){ return Math.cos(x)}]);

    // intersection
    var curve = app.board.create('curve', [[], []], {strokeWidth: 0, fillColor: "#09f", fillOpacity: 0.8})
    curve.updateDataArray = function() {
        var a = JXG.Math.Clip.intersection(circle, func, this.board);
        this.dataX = a[0];
        this.dataY = a[1]
    };
    app.board.update()
```

**Результат**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Ожидаемый результат (я делал это в Paint)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Fill the intersection area between circle and function in JSXGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68655862/7394871) от участника  [@Porizm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1644529/porizm).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/68655862/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Это можно легко реализовать с помощью следующей версии `JSXGraph`, которая выйдет на следующей неделе: с помощью элемента неравенства можно отметить область над кривой косинуса. Элемент неравенства представляет собой замкнутую кривую, которую можно пересечь окружностью. В v1.2.3 пересечение не работает из-за небольшой ошибки.

Что касается отсечения, следующая версия содержит новые элементы `curveintersection`, `curveunion`, `curvedifference`, которые упрощают использование методов `JXG.Math.Clip`, но, конечно, ваш подход с JXG.Math.Clip по-прежнему будет работать.

Вот код:

```
var f = board.create('functiongraph', ['cos(x)']);
var ineq = board.create('inequality', [f], {
            inverse: true, fillOpacity: 0.1
        });
var circ = board.create('circle', [[0,0], 4]);

var clip = board.create('curveintersection', [ineq, circ], {
            fillColor: 'yellow', fillOpacity: 0.6
        });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фактически, элемент неравенства делает то же самое, что и enxaneta «вручную».

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68677877/7394871) от участника  [@Alfred Wassermann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3336514/alfred-wassermann).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

В следующем примере я создаю атрибут `d` для пути с помощью `Math.cos()`. Я полагаю, ваша функция может быть другой.
Обратите внимание, что в конце атрибута `d` путь закрывает верхнюю часть холста svg. Я использую `id="pth"` внутри `clipPath` и обрезаю им круг.

```js
let d ="M";

for(let x = -50; x<=50; x+=1){
  d+=`${x}, ${5*Math.cos(x/5)} `
}
d+="L50,-50L-50,-50z"
pth.setAttribute("d",d);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" width="200">
  <clipPath id="clip">
    <path id="pth"/>
  </clipPath>
  <circle r="45" clip-path="url(#clip)" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```

Чтобы лучше понять, как я строю путь, взгляните на следующий пример:

```js
let d ="M";

for(let x = -50; x<=50; x+=1){
  d+=`${x}, ${5*Math.cos(x/5)} `
}
d+="L50,-50L-50,-50z"
pth.setAttribute("d",d);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" width="200">
  <circle r="45" fill="blue"/>
  <path id="pth" fill="rgba(250,0,0,.4)"/> 
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68656192/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>